# SharePoint 2010 Sort View By Total Column Count

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is there a solution to sort a view by total column count?

For example lets say I have a list with the following total columns.

50 apples
70 oranges
20 lemons
60 cherries

I would like to sort the list to show

70 oranges
60 cherries
50 apples
20 lemons

Comment: You can't arrange it OOTB. But, are you willing to use jquery ?  http://jebaird.com/2010/12/29/dragtable-a-jquery-ui-widget-to-re-arrange-table-columns-via-drag-and-drop.html or https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5464219%2Fchange-table-columns-order&ei=mrwYVN_KHYLiywOQ5oCICQ&usg=AFQjCNHOBvFYyFVXeqMVZKXSl4lABQxBdw&sig2=QLfxER_cRkgftqUfAPx1dA

Comment: hmm thank you for the suggestion I will take a look. The reason I am looking for a solution is that I am creating a web chart from these lists (the lists contains 1000+ items) and I would like to show the charts in an ascending order based on the total # of column.